# How to make Dynamic legend for VizFrame

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I am creating an XML view in SAPUI5, where i am using VizFrame Chart. I gave the `Measure` value a fixed  name as i am not sure how to make it dynamic as per select. The use case is on select, the measure value/legend on the chart should change as per the selected item.  [Image here][1]

The XML code:

```xml
 <viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}" vizProperties="{ title: {text : 'Energy', visible : true}, plotArea: {dataLabel:{visible: true} ,colorPalette :  ['#eab64d','#cb8589'] }}"
            height='100%' width="100%" vizType='line'>
            <viz:dataset>
                <viz.data:FlattenedDataset data="{/T_TABLE}">
                    <viz.data:dimensions>
                        <viz.data:DimensionDefinition name="Timeline"
                            value="{
                                    path: 'C_READINGTIMESTAMP',
                                    type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
                                formatOptions: {  

                                    pattern : 'dd/MM hh a'
                                 }}" />
                    </viz.data:dimensions>
                    <viz.data:measures>
                        <viz.data:MeasureDefinition name="Value"
                            value="{C_READINGVALUE}" />

                    </viz.data:measures>
                </viz.data:FlattenedDataset>
            </viz:dataset>

            <viz:feeds>
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='valueAxisFeed' uid="valueAxis" type="Measure"
                    values="Value" />
                <viz.feeds:FeedItem id='categoryAxisFeed' uid="categoryAxis" type="Dimension"
                    values="Timeline" />
            </viz:feeds>
        </viz:VizFrame>
```

Thanks for help. SOLVED IT. Used `jQuery` and made it dynamic on user click

Comment: Please have a look at [this example from Explored](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Bullet/preview).
Here you can play around with “Series”, “Axis Title” and “Values Displayed”.

You can also look at the coding [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.viz.sample.Bullet/code)
Is this what you are looking for?
Maybe you can post a screenshot, how it looks now and how you want it to look like?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sure i'll try that out. I have attached an image to my original question. You can see that there are some Energy, voltage parameter in the dropdown. On their select, I need the current hardcoded `value` to change to whatever was selected in the dropdown. Eg if Energy selected , then change measure axis legend, and tille name  to energy. If Voltage, then change to voltage. Right now its hardcoded as Value.